# SQL on creating a temporary coloumn

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Actually am trying to create a temporary column in the output:

E.g.:

```
Name    sold_cost  
jjj      900
hhh      -600
```

Desired output:

```
name   in_profit   in_loss
jjj     900          -
hhh      -           -600
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `case` expression with separate expressions for `in_profit` and `in_loss`:

```
SELECT name,
       CASE WHEN sold_cost > 0 THEN sold_cost ELSE '-' END AS in_profit,
       CASE WHEN sold_cost < 0 THEN sold_cost ELSE '-' END AS in_loss
FROM   my_table
```

Comment: but am getting null in remaining places can i just get - or empty space

Comment: @jagadeeshreddy you can just add an `else` clause to each of the `case` expressions - see my edited answer.